# Charts / Swift 3.0 - fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, charts, fatal-error, linechart

Recently I added https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts to my project where I have a segmentControl with time range (1D, 3M, 1Y, 5Y) to perform network call and fetch data from Yahoo.

First, I had to add a method for my String values for x-axis with the following:

```
class XAxisStringValueFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
    private var sValues: [String] = []
    init(values: [String]) {
        sValues = values
    }
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return sValues[Int(value)]
    }
}
```

In my LineChartViewController, I have a delegate for the timeRange change to perform my networkCall:

```
 func networkCall(range: ChartRange) {
        let symbol = self.symbol
        YahooFinanceApiClient.requestEquityChartpoints(symbol: symbol, range: range, onSuccess: { chartpts in
            self.createLineChart(range: range, chartpoints: chartpts)
            }, onError: { error in
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        })
    }
```

Here is my create Line ChartView:

```
func createLineChart(range: ChartRange, chartpoints: [EquityChartpoint]) {
        // set data
        var xValues: [String] = []
        var yValues: [Double] = []
        for object in chartpoints {
            switch range {
            case .OneDay:
                let x = Formatters.sharedInstance.stringFromHours(date: object.date)
                xValues.append(x!)
            case .ThreeMonth, .OneYear, .FiveYear:
                let x = Formatters.sharedInstance.stringFromDate(date: object.date)
                xValues.append(x!)
            }
            let y = object.close
            yValues.append(y!)
        }
        // charting
        let formatter: XAxisStringValueFormatter = XAxisStringValueFormatter(values: xValues)
        let xaxis: XAxis = XAxis()
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        for i in 0..<xValues.count {
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: yValues[i], data: xValues as AnyObject)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }
        xaxis.valueFormatter = formatter

        let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Price")

        let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: [lineChartDataSet])
        self.lineChartView.data = data
        self.lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xaxis.valueFormatter  
    }
```

I have a Fatal Error - Index out of range when I moved from "3M" to "1Y". I checked the xValues count to match yValues for each time range. It appears the error arrived at that xAxisStringValueFormatter where yValues count does not match the xValues. Seems strange to me. Anyone has some idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this ? I am having the exact same issue, when I select a year period, it crashes with Index Out Of Range...

Comment: @kobe. I changed the ChartFormatter to the following: 
    open var sValues: [String]! = []
    
    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return sValues[Int(value) % sValues.count]
    }

Comment: Also, made sure that the xValues count is equal to yValues before I draw the chart else put in an error handling method.

Comment: I am always getting this error when array with the values to display has only 1 value to, if `I have 0 or multiple I don't have any issues. So for me it doesn't seem to be an issue with the xAxis or yAxis values.

Answer (score 9):

Index out of range for line chart graph or Bar chart Graph. When the reading is 1. Please do the following changes in the Protocol of IAxisValueFormatter.

```
func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {      
    return myArr[Int(value) % myArr.count]
}
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :-) please look at [answer]

Comment: Its helped me! Thank you @Vipul

Answer (score 0):

```
func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
    let a = ""
    if(myArr.count>0)
    {
        return myArr[Int(value) % myArr.count]
    }
    return a
   
}
```